# Hybris API Command example usage for creating a customer

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am somewhat new to the Hybris API, and how to work with it, and so, I am trying to experiment with creating a new customer, called “Jolly Rodgers”…

I am trying to create a customer for the Hybris Accelerator Store “apparel-de”, but I do not seem to be getting the correct response:

With this:

a.  I am using a REST Client.

b.  I retreieve the authorization token and get:

c.  I get the response:

```
{
    "access_token": "0da83a86-6dd6-4526-a233-3d947b9040c1",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 36000
}
```

d.  I next attempt to create a new customer using the Hybris/OCC commands, using the following:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: bearer 0da83a86-6dd6-4526-a233-3d947b9040" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: b156f52b-4b43-ec3d-44ea-d98a48410dc7" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" http://localhost:9001/rest/v1/apparel-de/customers?login=jolly.rodgers@mail.com&password=password1&firstName=Jolly&lastName=Rodgers&titleCode=mr
```

**I get a message indicating that it could not get any response… any suggestions???**

Comment: Wild guess, but shouldn't you use `https://localhost:9002`? Can you post the error message you received? Maybe this documentation about errors would help you : https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Error+Responses+from+OCC+Web+Services

Answer (score -1):

why   are you using  OCC for Creating  Customer?

traditional  way is to use HMC.  HMC  >  Users

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I can, but I am working on a project where we are testing web store behaviour via the API... the client will later use these for building the web-front end, and so I using this example, and others to bring myself up to speed with OCC... I hope this help...

Any suggested solutions... as I am sure I have made a syntatical error???

Comment: HMC or `traditional` ways does not work fine when you have third party implementations, or process automations.